# In how far is language involved in the world of ideas?

Tags: language, idea

Language is a means to express ideas or emotions. It sets them free from the world in which they roam, i.e. our brain between our ears, inside our skulls.

It could work the other way too. Language being used to create or change ideas.

Which parts of language are more effective for responsive use, and which for transformative use? Or, to try to crystallize the question more intuitively, in the practice of [conlanging](https://conlang.org/), which subpractices help us understand responsiveness vs. transformation?

Put in such terms, the question also indicates bidirectional functions (functions effective for expression of previous ideas *as well as* construction of new ones).

Comment: I would recommend checking out the site FAQ for pointers on asking questions, here. There, it is said that we are to avoid asking questions in terms such as, "What's your opinion on so-and-so?" I just woke up from an exciting, romantic dream so I'm in an extra-good mood, and so I'm going to just edit your post rather than VTC, but do keep the site FAQ in mind in the future. ;) [Although also note that your question, such as it is, has already been asked on this site before.]